# How to give a DIV the width of its content?

Tags: css

I would like to give a DIV the width of the picture in its content.

Here is my HTML :

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="picandtext">
       <img src="https://placehold.it/480x320" />
       <p>Eodem tempore etiam Hymetii praeclarae indolis viri negotium est actitatum, cuius hunc novimus esse textum. cum Africam pro consule regeret Carthaginiensibus victus inopia iam lassatis, ex horreis Romano populo destinatis frumentum dedit, pauloque postea cum provenisset segetum copia, integre sine ulla restituit mora.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS :

```
#container { height: 600px; display:table; width:1%; background: red; padding:10px; }
#picandtext { height: 400px; display:table; width:1%; background: green; padding:10px; }
#picandtext img { height: 180px; }
#picandtext p { height: 180px; }
```

I finally found a way to do it with `display:table; width:1%;` as you can see with this JSFiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/Ls750c64/2/

But I would like to know if this way is the best one to make it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your existing markup, you can make `#container` `display: inline-block;` and absolutely position the `p` with text.

```css
#container {
  height: 600px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

#picandtext {
  height: 400px;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

#picandtext img {
  height: 180px;
}

#picandtext p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <div id="picandtext">
       <img src="https://placehold.it/480x320" />
       <p>Eodem tempore etiam Hymetii praeclarae indolis viri negotium est actitatum, cuius hunc novimus esse textum. cum Africam pro consule regeret Carthaginiensibus victus inopia iam lassatis, ex horreis Romano populo destinatis frumentum dedit, pauloque postea cum provenisset segetum copia, integre sine ulla restituit mora.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

And a less supported way to do it would be using intrinsic sizing. The browser support for it sucks though. http://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width

```css
#container {
  height: 600px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: min-content;
}

#picandtext {
  height: 400px;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

#picandtext img {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <div id="picandtext">
       <img src="https://placehold.it/480x320" />
       <p>Eodem tempore etiam Hymetii praeclarae indolis viri negotium est actitatum, cuius hunc novimus esse textum. cum Africam pro consule regeret Carthaginiensibus victus inopia iam lassatis, ex horreis Romano populo destinatis frumentum dedit, pauloque postea cum provenisset segetum copia, integre sine ulla restituit mora.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution seems to me smarter and cleaner. :)

Comment: @Guillaume you're welcome! Yeah it works as long as you've defined a height for the parent. Unfortunately that's the only way I know how to do that with just CSS. It's easy with javascript though!

Comment: @Guillaume just remembered another way and updated my answer. That's a much better way to do it, but browser support really sucks. Not supported at all in IE.